# Как поставить цикл while на паузу с помощью keyboard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, python-keyboard

Всем привет, делаю небольшой кликер с залипанием клавиши для игры через библиотеку keyboard. Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу остановить цикл при нажатии на клавишу P-p с дальнейшим перезапуском. Как решить данную проблему, подскажите пожалуйста.

Нужно, чтобы скрипт по нажатию на клавишу p останавливался и по нажатию клавиши l снова запускался.

```
import keyboard
import time

print('Start: l')
keyboard.wait('l') #Запустить цикл
while True:
    keyboard.press('w') #Клик
    if keyboard.is_pressed('p'): #Остановить цикл
       keyboard.wait('l') #Перезапустить цикл
```

Comment: еще один бесконечный цикл по прирыванию по клавише

Answer (score 0):

Как подметили в комментариях вы можете создавать ещё один цикл как здесь:

```
import keyboard
import time


keyboard.wait("l")
print("Start")
while True:
    print("Main is started.")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
        while True:
            print("Main is stoped")
            if keyboard.is_pressed("l"):
                break;
```